# draw a line from a stationary point to a moving point on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drawing

How can I draw a line between one point (the center of one UIView) to a point that moves (touch location), and the line moves the 2nd point as the touch moves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your custom view:

- in touchesMoved:withEvent store current point into a variable, and call `[self setNeedsDisplay]` so that the view would redraw
- implement drawing of a line in `drawRect:`, use core graphics to draw a line

Let's say you store the touched point into property `self.touchedPoint`, then drawing might look like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint touchedPoint;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();       
 CGContextSaveGState(context);

 CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, rect.size.height);
 CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

 CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, YES);
 CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
 CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0);

 CGContextMoveToPoint(context, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2);
 CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.touchedPoint.x, self.touchedPoint.y);
 CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke); 

 CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.touchedPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I voted Michal's answer up. But I would also suggest looking at the [Touches](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project. It is easy to get it running - which may be helpful if you are still just putting together your project.